# Leer un archivo .JSON con múltiples arrays codificados en el mismo

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando en un plug-in o extensión para un servidor Minecraft: PE, en donde se guarda cada mensaje escrito en el chat público, incluyendo variada información como sus coordenadas al enviar el mensaje, su dinero, experiencia, entre otros.

Con el objetivo de concretar esto, se crea un array en PHP, con sus respectivas values ya definidas, y posteriormente se codifica a formato JSON, por último se consigue el nombre del jugador, siendo $jugador.json el archivo que se creará si no existe, o se reescribirá, todo esto usando fwrite() en modo a+.

En fwrite(), después de la variable con la información codificada, en la misma línea, agrego dos saltos de línea (\n) para poder intentar hacer lo que voy a explicar a continuación:

Necesito poder decodificar esta información (un archivo .JSON) que almacena varios array, cada uno, al final, tiene saltos de línea.

Este es un archivo de ejemplo que puse en mi servidor web:
https://survivaltimepe.com/ejemplo.txt

De esto, sabiendo el nombre del jugador ($jugador.json, es decir sabiendo el nombre del archivo en un directorio x), necesito buscar una coincidencia en $decodificado['msg'].

Lo que necesito es que, sea capaz de decodificar todos los arrays en el archivo, identificándolos con los dos saltos de línea particulares al final de cada uno de ellos, y que consiga el ['msg'] (seguramente necesitaré hacer un foreach loop por cada array).

Luego de esto, si hay coincidencias, o el mensaje es el mismo que la coincidencia que estoy buscando, necesito que me dé el array (completo) en el que está ubicado la coincidencia, por supuesto, decodificado.

Resumen:

- Variable $archivo o ruta al archivo: la tengo: ejemplo: $this->getDataFolder()."/messages/jugador/04-06-2017.json"

-. Variable $coincidencia, basándome en el ejemplo del link dado, 
$coincidencia es "and p".

- Regresa el array 3 (último) , ya que "and p" es la coincidencia más cercana a "msg" en los arrays "and past"

Gracias.

Comment: y que has intentado?

Answer (score 2):

Como el fichero en cuestión no es un único json, sino que son varios, se puede hacer fácilmente leyendo cada línea del fichero con `file()`, que devuelve una array donde cada índice almacena una línea del fichero. Recorremos el array comprobando que hay contenido (Otras comprobaciones pueden realizarse, esto solo es un ejemplo ilustrativo) y una vez procesado el contenido JSON, lo añadimos a un array que contenta todos los elementos. En este caso, uso un segundo parámetro en la función json_decode para asegurarme que todo lo que se almacena es una array y no un objeto de tipo 'StdClass'

```
<?php 

$fileContent = file('https://survivaltimepe.com/ejemplo.txt');

$arrayContent = [];

foreach ($fileContent as $fileLine) {

    if (trim($fileLine) != '') {

        $arrayContent[] = json_decode($fileLine, true);

    }

}
?>

<pre>
    <?php print_r($arrayContent); ?>
</pre>
```